# How Efficient Are Intrinsic (Math) Functions in Fortran?

Tags: performance, fortran

How efficient are Fortran's (90+) intrinsic (math) functions? I especially care about tanh and sech but am interested in the other Fortran intrinsic functions as well.

By "how efficient" I mean that if it is very hard to come up with a faster method then the intrinsics are efficient but if it is very easy to come up with a faster method then the intrinsics are inefficient.

Here is a MWE, in which my change to try to make it faster actually made it slower, suggesting the intrinsics are efficient.

```
program main
implicit none

integer, parameter :: n = 10000000
integer  :: i
real :: x, var
real :: t1,t2,t3,t4

!! Intrinsic first
call cpu_time(t1)
do i = 1, n
  x = REAL(i)/300.0
  var = tanh(x)
end do
call cpu_time(t2)
write(*,*) "Elapsed CPU Time = ", t2 - t1
write(*,*) var

!! Intrinsic w/ small change
call cpu_time(t3)
do i = 1, n
  x = REAL(i)/300.0
  if (x > 10.0) then
    var = 1.0
  else
    var = tanh(x)
  end if
end do
call cpu_time(t4)
write(*,*) "Elapsed CPU Time = ", t4 - t3            
write(*,*) var

end program main
```

Note that Fortran90 seems to be lazy; if I don't include the "write(*,*) var" then it says elapsed CPU time = 0.0

Comment: IMHO it seems unlikely that a compiler called **Formula Translater** that has specialised in mathematical and scientific analysis since around 1960 wouldn't be pretty optimised by now...

Comment: If you search hard enough, even here on SO, you are likely to find algorithms for computing trigonometric functions which trade accuracy for speed, ie which are faster but less accurate than the intrinsics.  But I seriously doubt that any time you spend looking for algorithms which are as fast and as accurate as the intrinsics will be anything other than a waste of your time.  I'm not sure that it is relevant that you are programming in Fortran, I expect any other compiled language on the same platform would use the same library functions for `tanh` *etc*

Comment: Do you have a particular compiler in mind? Intel, for example, has `-fast transcendentals`, which trades accuracy for speed. See here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522971

Comment: Also, are you sure transcendental calculations are really your bottleneck? I would do some testing - in my experience, other issues such as mis-predicted branches and cache misses cause more slowdown. It's almost certainly application dependent, though.

Comment: *Note that Fortran90 seems to be lazy ...*  Not so much.  If a program doesn't use the results of a piece of code a smart compiler will simply optimise it away.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If you'd like me to remove the question, say so. Otherwise, I think your first comment is an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Ross Thanks for the Intel tip. I will be using an intel compiler but I was also interested in "best practice" - which HPM indicates is to use the intrinsics.

Comment: GCC has a similar option `-ffast-math`. The math intrinsics are the same in Fortran and in C.

Comment: Your cpu_time probably doesn't measure intervals < .01 sec so you can't conclude performance there.  As already mentioned , an optimization might skip unused iterations

Comment: I generally get more bang for the buck by having functions in libraries and marking them as ELEMENTAL and vector or SIMD attributes. Usually the layout and the prefetch helps a lot, and the Intel compiler spits out vetpctor reports. There are no reason I have found to believe that the intrinsics are anything but solid and fast, and more often than not they are ELEMENTAL. So a structure of arrays breezes through, but an array of structures can be slow depending on how you order the operations. When your own function is vectorised/SIMD/ELEMENTAL enabled acts as fast as an intrinsic.